# Getting start- and end time when status changed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a table with devices and their state. Every 5 minutes the state of each device is saved into the database. Each record in the database contains the name of the device (ABC, DEF etc..), the state of the device (1 = OK, 6 = down and 11 = planned down), the time the record was added to the database and the date the record was added.

Now I would like to have the start and end time when the status change of each device.

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `StateN` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `TimeAdded` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `DateAdded` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

INSERT INTO `demo` (`Id`, `Name`, `StateN`, `TimeAdded`, `DateAdded`) VALUES
  (1, 'ABC', 1, 1540250401, 1540245600),
  (2, 'DEF', 1, 1540250401, 1540245600),
  (3, 'GHI', 1, 1540250401, 1540245600),
  (4, 'JKL', 11,1540250401, 1540245600),

  (5, 'ABC', 1, 1540250701, 1540245600),
  (6, 'DEF', 1, 1540250701, 1540245600),
  (7, 'GHI', 1, 1540250701, 1540245600),
  (8, 'JKL', 11, 1540250701, 1540245600),

  (9, 'ABC', 1, 1540251001, 1540245600),
  (10, 'DEF', 1, 1540251001, 1540245600),
  (11, 'GHI', 6, 1540251001, 1540245600),
  (12, 'JKL', 11, 1540251001, 1540245600),

  (13, 'ABC', 1, 1540251301, 1540245600),
  (14, 'DEF', 1, 1540251301, 1540245600),
  (15, 'GHI', 6, 1540251301, 1540245600),
  (16, 'JKL', 11, 1540251301, 1540245600),

  (17, 'ABC', 1, 1540251601, 1540245600),
  (18, 'DEF', 1, 1540251601, 1540245600),
  (19, 'GHI', 1, 1540251601, 1540245600),
  (20, 'JKL', 11,1540251601, 1540245600);
```

And I would like to have the following output:

```
Name StateN StartTime  EndTime
ABC  1      1540250401 1540251601
DEF  1      1540250401 1540251601
GHI  1      1540250401 1540250701
GHI  6      1540251001 1540251301
GHI  1      1540251601 1540251601
JKL  11     1540250401 1540251601
```

Comment: I don't understand the first 'GHI' result

Comment: Sorry, the end time must be 1540250701, not 1540250401. I have edited the excepted result.

Answer (score 0):

This returns something similar to what you're after, which makes me suspect that there's an error in your result set...

```
SELECT name
     , staten
     , MIN(timeadded) starttime
     , MAX(timeadded) endtime
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT name
                   , staten
                   , timeadded
                   , CASE WHEN @prev_name = name 
                          THEN CASE WHEN @prev_staten = staten 
                                    THEN @i:=@i 
                                    ELSE @i:=@i+1 END 
                          ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
                   , @prev_name := name prev_name
                   , @prev_staten:=staten prev_state
                FROM demo
               ORDER 
                  BY name
                   , timeadded
                   , staten
            ) a
         JOIN
            ( SELECT @prev_name := null, @prev_staten := null, @i:=0) vars
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY name
     , staten
     , i
 ORDER
    BY name
     , starttime
     , staten;

+------+--------+------------+------------+
| name | staten | starttime  | endtime    |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
| ABC  |      1 | 1540250401 | 1540251601 |
| DEF  |      1 | 1540250401 | 1540251601 |
| GHI  |      1 | 1540250401 | 1540250701 |
| GHI  |      6 | 1540251001 | 1540251301 |
| GHI  |      1 | 1540251601 | 1540251601 |
| JKL  |     11 | 1540250401 | 1540251601 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: The query is resulting in all records with the same timestamp in start time and end time. Is there something going wrong in the group by?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4otgmivM6VNaA529TRcB3J/0

Comment: I think it's a bug in dbfiddle

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: this is incorrect answer as I missed "when the status change" part in OP.

```
SELECT
      Name
    , StateN
    , MIN(TimeAdded)
    , MAX(TimeAdded)
FROM
    demo
GROUP BY
    Name, StateN
;
```